# C# console application passing NameValueCollection from one class to another

Tags: c#, .net

I'm learning C# but I'm having trouble with passing the data NameValueCollection from one class to another in my console application, I'm experienced in using java  but from reading about passing by value and passing by reference has me stumped. My demo code below of the two classes is as follows, my helper class.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Helper
    {
        public void Dostuff()
        {
            string name = "valves";
            int num = 5;
            NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
            collection.Add("Sam", "Dot Net Perls");
            collection.Add("Bill", "Microsoft");

        }

        public NameValueCollection GetCollection()
        {
            NameValueCollection coll2 = Dostuff.Collection();
            return coll2;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my program class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Helper h1 = new ConsoleApplication3.Helper();
            NameValueCollection newcollection = h1.GetCollection();
            RandomInbuiltMethod(newcollection);
        }


    }
}
```

I'm not handling the passing of the NameValueCollection data properly and I don't want to make the helper methods static, Is there a way to do this, I'm sure I'm over creating the complexity and using to much resources for the Helper class, can anyone show me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to return the collection created in the DoStuff method of the Helper class

```
class Helper
{
    private NameValueCollection Dostuff()
    {
        string name = "valves";
        int num = 5;
        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("Sam", "Dot Net Perls");
        collection.Add("Bill", "Microsoft");
        return collection;
    }

    public NameValueCollection GetCollection()
    {
        return Dostuff();
    }
}
```

Now, your main method will retrieve the collection with the values added inside the DoStuff method